# jqueryUI datetimepicker not showing correctly

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, frontend

Good day people,

I am currently following [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1136464/Simplest-Way-to-Use-JQuery-Date-Picker-and-Date-Ti) for implementing a jQuery datetimepicker. I use C#, MVC and Bootstrap. I am using the default configuration for ASP.NET (I created a default MVC project) just added jQuery UI.

I have done all the steps, you can see my code here:

```
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
 {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryUI").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/JqueryUICSS").Include(
                 "~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css"));
 }
```

The HTML using razor:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>

/**add here the date of birth*/
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth,
new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control date-picker" } })
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Genre, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
       
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Genre, true)
    <span>Hombre</span>

    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Genre, false)
    <span>Mujer</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

And the script section:

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryUI")
@Scripts.Render("~/Content/JqueryUICSS")
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () { $(".date-picker").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: "-100:+0",
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
            });
     });
</script>
```

As a result I am obtaining this [bad display in datetimepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa1Sa.png).

How can I fix this? thanks.

Comment: Because you have  included `jquery` after the other scripts (wiping the out). You have also not included the relevant css file

Comment: Include the style of `jquery ui css`

Comment: This jQuery insertion line must be placed first: `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>`. Also include jQuery UI CSS bundles you want to use by using `StyleBundle` & `Styles.Render`.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comments, I realized that when I render the bundle for css, I used the word @Scripts.Render("~/Content/JqueryUICSS") instead of @Styles.Render("~/Content/JqueryUICSS"), thanks!